# Should be a static inner class find bug error on Lombok @Data inner class

Tags: java, findbugs, lombok

I have class

```
class SomeClass{

}
```

And static nested class in them:

```
@Data
public static class CrmOpioLogFilter {
    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;
    private List<String> filterCrmGroupIds;
    private String msisdn;
    private List<CrmUser> crmUsers;
    private List<OperationType> operationTypes;
    private List<OpioLogState> states;
}
```

And find bug say error:

```
Should SomeClass$CrmOpioLogFilter be a _static_ inner class?
```

> Should be a static inner class This class is an inner class, but does
>   not use its embedded reference to the object which created it.  This
>   reference makes the instances of the class larger, and may keep the
>   reference to the creator object alive longer than necessary.  If
>   possible, the class should be made static.

And show this lines:

```
1 @Data
2 private Date fromDate;
3 private Date toDate;
```

I know Date is mutable and rewrite class:

```
@Data
    public static class CrmOpioLogFilter {
        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private Date fromDate;
        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private Date toDate;
        private List<String> filterCrmGroupIds;
        private String msisdn;
        private List<CrmUser> crmUsers;
        private List<OperationType> operationTypes;
        private List<OpioLogState> states;

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = new Date(fromDate.getTime());
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = new Date(toDate.getTime());
    }

        public Date getFromDate() {
            return new Date(fromDate.getTime());
        }

        public Date getToDate() {
            return new Date(toDate.getTime());
        }
    }
```

But findbug show error does not matter.

Comment: Ignore it. Yet another FindBugs bug. Could the authors of FindBug please note that 'static inner' is a contradiction in terms, and that 'keep the reference ... alive' is completely meaningless. And please note yourself that your class is static, not inner.

Comment: "And please note yourself that your class is static, not inner." My CrmOpioLogFilter contains inside SomeClass

Comment: Irrelevant. It is declared as static. An inner class is a nested class that is *not* declared `static`. Source: [JLS #8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

Comment: If I use this class like filter into my Bean class How will it be right? static or not?

Comment: I like it the way it is,`static`. That's what FindBugs wants too, even though it wrongly thinks it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two choices here:

A) Lombok creates invalid bytecode, then findbugs is correct

B) findbugs gives you an invalid warning

You can now use javap to disassemble your classes to identify the culprit. To then study documentation in more depth or maybe write up a bug report to that tool.